# Как правильно вставить и стилизовать svg в данном случае?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

Добрый день. Ситуация в следующем - делаем сайт на wordpress, где будет присутствовать список ссылок на аккаунты в соцсетях. С иконками этих самых соцсетей.
 Требование заказчика - чтобы в админке можно было загружать иконки в виде svg-файлов. Этот список выводится на страницу в нескольких местах, и по дизайну в одном месте эти иконки белого цвета, в другом - черного. Более того - они должны менять цвет при наведении. 
Поскольку загружаются они из админки, отдельными файлами, ни о каком спрайте речь не идет. Также, поскольку загружаются они единожды в одном месте - о нескольких документах с отличающимся `fill` речь тоже не идет. Грубо говоря, мы имеем, например, иконку фейсбука, которая в зависимости от расположения на сайте должна быть черной либо белой, а также менять при наведении цвет - ну, скажем, на красный. И файл иконки должен быть один единственный.

Чтобы были возможны манипуляции с `fill`, `stroke` и т.д., иконку необходимо вставить именно как svg-документ. Но я заранее не знаю, с каким именно документом придется иметь дело, поэтому максимум, что я смог придумать - это в php выводить ссылку на загруженный svg-документ в атрибут блока `data-icon`, а потом в js написать код, который проходится циклом по этим блокам, выдергивает строку из `data-icon` и формирует svg таким образом:

```
$(this).append('<object type="image/svg+xml" data="' + $(this).attr("data-icon") + '" class="icon"></object>');
```

И все бы ничего, но , поскольку встраивание элемента атрибута `data` это что-то вроде `iframe` - то обратиться в стилях к svg невозможно. Вставка через `svg use` тоже не работает, т.к. просто напрямую обратиться к файлу нельзя, нужно прописать `id` конкретного элемента внутри файла. А одному богу известно, какие там в дальнейшем файлы будет загружать заказчик.

В общем, описал проблему и попытки решения. Может быть есть все-таки какое-то иное решение?

Comment: Вы всерьез полагаете, что все остальные, кто задает вопросы на этом ресурсе, делают это исключительно в священных научно-образовательных целях, и, боже упаси, ни в коем случае, не решают тут рабочие вопросы?

Comment: так вы всё уже придумали. Вставить в `html` посредством тега `<object>` svg файл с иконками соц. сетей. Но внутри svg обязательно нужно удалить атрибуты `fill` и `stroke` у иконок. А дальше раскрашивайте иконки с помощью JS в зависимости от расположения иконок.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что не работает. JS не видит, что находится внутри <object>, поскольку тег svg со всеми своими потомками находится не прямо в теге object, а внутри #document. Это что-то вроде iframe получается, и внутрь этого #document не попасть ни стилями, ни скриптами. А проверка на содержание object.contentDocument сообщает, что он пустой. В консоли выводится что внутри #document только <html><body></body></html> и всё. Но по факту-то это не так...

Comment: и правильно, `JS` не будет работать напрямую с <object>,  но с иконками которые лежат внутри файла спрайта добавленными через 'object' и вызванными через  <svg ....> <use xlink:href="#facebook" /> </svg> будет работать

Comment: Да, но это ведь не спрайт, в том-то и дело. Каждая иконка - отдельный svg-файл, содержание которого теоретически мне вообще неизвестно. Я ведь получаю в коде просто ссылку на файл в виде строки, например (wp-content/themes/some_theme/img/icons/facebook.svg), и потом эту строку присваиваю как атрибут data тега object. При таком раскладе я, получается, вообще не имею доступа к внутренностям svg, и даже не могу знать, прописаны ли там fill и stroke((

Comment: так объясните это всё заказчику и предложите свой вариант, сделать полный набор иконок с различными цветами: Facebook-Black; Facebook-White; Facebook-Red и не нужно тогда изобретать ничего. Просто вызывать нужную иконку в нужном месте.

Comment: Да, видимо, так и придется сделать, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Никаких танцев с бубном, всё до смешного просто:

```
$(this).load($(this).attr("data-icon"));
```

И не нужно никаких object, use и прочего!

Comment: Спасибо! Думаю, кто-нибудь уже запатентовал :)